# React component rerendering even with key. Input losing focus

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Here I've provided a stripped down version of my component. Basically it contains an array of "phases" that change what is shown. My problem is that even though everything has a key, it re-renders the input on every change and the input loses focus after every character is typed. How can I correctly structure this to signal to React that this component should not be re-rendered?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Example({ history }) {
  const [phase, setPhase] = useState(0)
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  let Phases = []

  Phases[0] = () => {
    return (
      <div key='keyK1'>
        <div key='yourkeyinputcontainer'>
          <input placeholder='Input' type='text' value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} key='yourinputbox'></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const Content = Phases[phase]

  return (
    <>
      <Content key='contentkey' />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: the array is being recreated every time you are updating the input value.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a component of your input fields ( your `phases` ) separately and try to use `memo(Content)` on them, to avoid re-rendering when the value not changed, and after you created the component of your phases with different names all you need to do is :

```
export default memo(Content)
```

also if you have a wrapper array to hold all of your phases, instead of simply putting it in a simple array like :

```
let Phases = []
```

you can use `useMemo` hook from react to handle it:

```
let Phases = useMemo(() => { return [] }, [...list of dependancies])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this. Instead of defining each phases, you can define a `phase component` and make it accept all the required data as props.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Phase = ({ key1, key2, key3, text, handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <div key={key1}>
      <div key={key2}>
        <input
          placeholder="Input"
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
          key={key3}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = ({ history }) => {
  const [phase, setPhase] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState("bbbb");
  // instead of defining whole component just define the data here and pass them as props
  const phases = [{ key1: "key1", key2: "key2", key3: "key3" }];
  const handleChange = value => {
    setText(value);
  };

  const content = phases[phase];

  return (
    <Phase
      key1={content.key1}
      key2={content.key2}
      key3={content.key3}
      text={text}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that each phase is structured differently. Each phase has its own unique elements.

Comment: then how about conditionally rendering each elements instead of storing them in an array?